# Google Analytics end session when page reloads

Tags: google-analytics

We use Google analytics for tracking in our webapp. When we update the document.location, does this automatically ends the Google analytics session?

When the user is idling for 30 seconds, we want to bring him to the start page again with:

```
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling location.reload() acts the same as clicking the refresh button in your browser.  Since it is not resetting the GA cookie, the GA session will not end.  By default, the GA session expires after 30 minutes of inactivity. See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en.

It is important to note that refreshing the page will be recognized as activity by GA.  If you are refreshing the page after 30 seconds of inactivity, the session will never expire assuming that the user never leaves the page.

If you would like to manually control when a GA session is started and ended, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#session.

Comment: Thanks Brian for the excellent answers! Inward clearly on the wrong track here. Thx!

Comment: So resetting the cookie ends the sessions? Is there a place there this is explained in the GA documentation? These doesn't seem to be any mention of that in the document on sessions you liked above.

Comment: @fraxture it is not mentioned anywhere that I know of.  Google must just assume that the implementor understands the concept that sessions are identified by a browser cookie.  With that said, it is a poor assumption on Google's part since the industry is evolving in a direction that non-technical users are able to implement experiments.  Perhaps it is mentioned in the Google Optimize docs somewhere as that tool requires minimal coding knowledge.

Comment: @Chris if your issue has been resolved, please accept the answer.  Trying to build up some SO cred ;).  Thanks!